# Is it possible to show a specific element of a webpage in an iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe, xpath

Say I have this code:

```
<iframe 
  src="https://www.test.com/test"
  height="720"
  width="1280">
</iframe>
```

Now let's say I want to only show a specific part of test.html. I'm not looking to crop the iframe and disable scrolling to show a part of the page, I would like to only show a specific element of the webpage in the iframe.

Is there a way to do this? Perhaps by xPath, CSS selector, etc.?

Comment: If it's a local iframe, can you just modify test.html to show what you want, then set the iframe dimensions to match? Or modify the CSS in the iframe to only show what you want? If not, assuming it's a local/same-origin iframe, you could do it with javascript.

Comment: @MichaelCoker it's accessing an external website.

Comment: So the `src` in your html above is incorrect? It should be an `http://` or `https://` link to some external page?

Comment: Yes, my bad! Thanks for catching that.